# split row into multiple sessions by time difference in pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here's the pseudo data:

```
user  ts
--------
1     1
1     3
1     10
1     13
1     21
1     24
```

It will be split into two sessions if adjacent time difference is >= 6 for each user. So, the above data should be split as below:

```
user    ts    diff
-------------------
1       1     None
1       3     2
-------------------
1       10    7
1       13    3
-------------------
1       21    8
1       24    3
```

I understand how to generate the diff column in `pyspark` via Window function illustrated below, but how could I split it into different sessions for each user in `pyspark` manner? Great thanks!

```
select
   user,
   ts,
   (lag(ts, 1) over (partition by user order by ts asc)) as diff
from user_event
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right beginning.  The SQL would continue as:

```
select user, ts, diff,
       sum(case when diff > 6 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by ts) as session_grouping
from (select user, ts,
             lag(ts, 1) over (partition by user order by ts asc) as diff
      from user_event
     ) ue;
```

Comment: That works! And after your examplary code above, I think I comprehend `over (partition by)` more thoroughly this time. Thanks a lot!